# How Hadoop -getmerge works?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

In hadoop getmerge description

> Usage: hdfs dfs -getmerge src localdst  [addnl]

My question is why getmerge is concatenating to the local destination why not hdfs itself ? This question was asked because i have this following problems

1. What if the files to be merged are more than the size of the local?
2. Is there any specific reason behind restricting hadoop -getmerge command to only to concatenate to local-destination?

Comment: I know that this is not your question, but perhaps you will find this post useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776339/hadoop-getmerge-to-another-machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getmerge` command has been created specifically for merging files from HDFS into a single file on local file system.

This command is very useful to download the output of a MapReduce job, which could have generated multiple part-* files and combine them into a single file locally, which you can use for other operations (for e.g. put it in an Excel sheet for presentation).

Answers to your questions:

1. If the destination file system does not have enough space, then IOException is thrown. The `getmerge` internally uses `IOUtils.copyBytes()` (see [IOUtils.copyBytes()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IOUtils.html#copyBytes(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration))) function to copy one file at a time from HDFS to local file. This function throws `IOException` whenever there is an error in the copy operation.
2. This command is on similar lines as `hdfs fs -get` command which gets the file from HDFS to local file system. Only difference is `hdfs fs -getmerge` merges multiple files from HDFS to local file system.

If you want to merge multiple files in HDFS, you can achieve it using `copyMerge()` method from `FileUtil` class (see [FileUtil.copyMerge()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String))).

This API copies all files in a directory to a single file (merges all the source files).

Comment: Is there an alternative for -getmerge where i can merge the files directly from hdfs to hdfs?

Comment: There is no command line functionality for that. As I mentioned in the answer, you need to use "FileUtil.copyMerge()" programmatically or use some Linux shell script tricks like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548259/merging-multiple-files-into-one-within-hadoop. For e.g. hadoop fs -cat [dir]/* | hadoop fs -put - [destination file]